# calendar clients ignoring FREEBUSY property in ical4j generated .ics file

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, icalendar, ical4j

I am using ical4j to generate the following ics file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//iOffice//iCal4j 1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20170116T180054Z
DTSTART:20170116T190000Z
DTEND:20170116T200000Z
SUMMARY:03-300C Houston
UID:Reservation#someuuid
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN=Markk Admin:mailto:email@test.com
FREEBUSY;FBTYPE=FREE:20170116T190000Z/20170116T200000Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

When I import this into google calendar, ical or outlook I am always 'shown as' busy ie the 3rd line from the bottom is being ignored by the clients.  Am I missing something?  Does anyone have an example file that I can import and see it set me to free?

Answer (score 2):

The Answer is to use the TRANSP:TRANSPARENT property not FREEBUSY despite all docs to the contrary